# Can ethanol and heat during distillation cause degradation/dissolution of vinyl tubing leading hot vapors of the distillate to the condenser?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, distillation, rubber

I'm a chemist and a qa lab, and we occasionally test herbal remedy products from one of our customers for alcohol content using a distillation, then using the specific gravity of the distillate to estimate alcohol content as if the distillate were a binary solution of ethanol and water. Almost all of the distillations I do result in a clear, transparent distillate, however today I tested a sample, and the distillate appeared a cloudy white. The tube I have leading vapors to the condenser was glass, but due to it being worn and damaged I changed it today using what I had on hand here, which was vinyl tubing. The tubing unfortunately only says vinyl so I don't know exactly what kind of vinyl polymer it is, but during distillation the tubing went from transparent to white. The alcohol content of the samples was 18.1% which is lower than the expected 20 - 30%. I'm wondering if the ethanol and or heat (or another chemical in the sample) was causing the degradation or dissolution of the tubing??

Can anyone help me find out if our tubing was degraded or dissolved in the process of distillation?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Even cold ethanol corrupts surface of many plastics. Using plastic tubing may not be a good idea, full glass apparatus is advised. Try to test the plastic behaviour with cold ethanol alone,  with heat alone and in hot ethanol.

Comment: A lot of standard "vinyl" tubing is plasticised PVC. It contains a *lot* of plasticiser (often phthalates) which is easy to displace from the tubing. Even when that tubing is used for inert gas only, this often accumulates in bends in the tubes over time. Hot gas passing through such tubes will extract a *lot* which is why you should never use such tubing anywhere where it will contact your reaction, solutions or distillate vapours. Your distillate will be heavily contaminated with plasticiser.

Comment: Both of these comments are very helpful. Thank you!